# XCode 4 User Script

Tags: xcode4

I use XCode for one year, and I made a user script in Python. This script gets the all document, gets the cursor position thanks to %%%{PBXSelectionStart}%%%, does some very useful stuff, and replaces all the current document, without moving the cursor.

It works fine.

But I upgraded to XCode 4 and it's seems that the user scripts are not supported! How can I continue to use my script ?

(I try with automator but I can't use the %%%{PBXSelectionStart}%%% variable for the cursor position and I must select all the document in XCode...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PaulR: Nice comment, but now obsolete :-P

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems like Apple dropped user script support :-( The only thing you can do is (from the Apple Developer Forum):

> Your only option is to drop it in
>   ~/Library/Scripts and then go to
>   File > Services > Service Preferences... and set a keyboard shortcut.

This works, but is only an inferior replacement, since you won't have all the possibilities you used to have with Xcode user scripts in Xcode 3 :-(

[Here is a post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/10/code-formatting-in-xcode-4/) showing you how to create an Automator Action which you can use as a service in Xcode (via the service menu and assign a shortcut as mentioned above). I did that as well (modifying one of my scripts to read input from stdin and write output to stdout) and it works... as I said above, it is rather limited and it is ten times slower than it used to, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

See https://devforums.apple.com/message/380673#380673 for an answer.

Comment: Of course, those of us who aren't registered developers can't see this…

Comment: It's copy pasted in the answer above, it was on NDA at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and put together a wrapper script that allows Xcode 4 to run Xcode 3 user scripts.

It works by replacing the old style %%%{PBXFilePath}%%% variables in your scripts with values gleamed from Xcode 4 via AppleScript.

Its available on GitHub. https://bitly.com/HXHiij